# Resources getting removed from terraform tfstate

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We write terraform code for AWS resources and store the tfstate in S3 bucket.
Lately, we see few of the resources are getting removed from tfstate.

e.g:- Our code creates the VPC, Subnets and Route Tables in single module. In tfstate, we see the Subnet & Route Table but no VPC.

If we have the versioning enabled in tfstate bucket, we just restore the last version and issue gets solved. But if there is no versioning enabled, it's a hassle to import.

Any idea why this could be happening? And how this can be solved.

Comment: Hi there. Without some more information is hard to help you. Do you have any code you can share that may have caused this? Any plan/apply output to share? Which Tf version are you on, have you updated it recently?

Comment: Never seen this. Could you put more details, like how you apply the things. when you run plan what is the output. May be it is saying VPC is updating in place.

Comment: We are using Terraform version 1.5.0 and the plan doesn't update anything. It says 3 to add; adding whichever is removed from tfstate

Comment: isn't it possible that someone run a terraform state rm operation you are not aware of?

Comment: No, and even if anyone would run the command all will be removed. Here few are there. For e.g security group is removed but security group rule is there. Also, we don't run the command directly. We have pipelines for the same.